# Variables form subclass to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Viewcontroller named: Selectvideo. this has a subclass named selectvideo1. how can i pass a int from the subclass to the viewcontroller? i've tried, but it will only return 0 everytime i try. In the subclass it return 0.

i'm trying pass the selectedCellValue from selectvideo1 to selectvideo. by using this:

selectvideo1.h

```
@interface SelectVideo1 : SelectVideo <UIActionSheetDelegate>


- (id)initWith:(NSString *)Selected;
    @property int selectedCellValue;

@end
```

selectvideo1.m

```
-(void)didComplete:(NSDictionary *)response

{


    SelectVideo *selectVideo = [[SelectVideo alloc] init];

    selectVideo.selectedRowValue = selectedCellValue;
}
```

selectvideo.h

```
@interface SelectVideo : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;
    -(IBAction)songsDone:(id)sender;

    @property int selectedRowValue;

@end
```

selectvideo.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{



    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%d", selectedRowValue);




}
```

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028965/send-integer-from-document-to-document. Did you understand the answer given there?

Comment: No since i had the heredity class misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused. You have 2 separate objects, so the fact that the SelectVideo1 class is a subclass of SelectVideo is not really relevant.

The fact that my convertible is a subclass of sedan does not mean that an instance of convertible can send information to another instance of sedan that is not a convertible through class methods. The 2 objects need to communicate with each other using property getter/setters or instance methods.

The code you posted should work - sort of. In your didComplete method, you create a new instance of the SelectVideo class and set that SelectVideo object's selectedRowValue class to selectedCellValue.

However, what do you do with this new instance of SelectVideo? In the code you posted, you create it as a local variable, set it's selectedRowValue property, and then discard it. When your didComplete method finishes, the new SelectVideo object you created will go out of scope and ARC will deallocate it.

This is like creating a new sedan object, setting it's radio station, and then pushing the new sedan off a cliff without ever driving it.

It seems to me you have some fundamental misunderstanding about what objects are, and what it means to allocate an object.

Where are you trying to send this information? Can you diagram your objects and explain what information you're trying to pass, from and to?

Comment: I've saved the indexpath.row from a viewcontroller to the object "selectedCellValue"(in selectvideo1). after this i want to pass this value to the selectvideo viewcontroller. 
I think your right about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding your "subclass".  Since your `SelectVideo1` is hereditary class of `SelectVideo` it inherits the variables and properties of the parent class.  The parent class has no knowledge of any subclasses or their variables.  If you want your superclass to have knowledge of a variable you need to define it there instead of in the subclass.

```
parentClass
{
   //variables and properties (example selectedRow)
}

childClass : parentClass (inherits all of the parentClass's variables, properties, functions, etc.
{
    //new variables and properties that the parentClass doesn't want to see
    //use any of parentClass's variables in this class's implementation.
}
```

Then you can use the properties and variables of parentClass in both classes, and the variables of childClass in only an instance of childClass.

Long story short.  Define the variables in the parentClass if you want to use them in parentClass.  The childClass will inherit them and be able to use them.

Comment: okay but how can i pass a variable from the hereditary class to the selectvideo?

Comment: You don't pass variables to a superclass.  You have an instance of an object.  You can refer to that object as it's own class, or it's superclass.  In either case the variables from the superclass are there to be used, read, written, etc.  I think heredity is not what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Putz, the OP is creating a new instance of the superclass. It doesn't really matter that it's an ancestor object. It's a different instance.

Answer (score 0):

Parent class(SuperClass) cannot access Subclass Properties but Subclass can Access/inherit all properties of Parent class(SuperClass). If you want to do it make a sharedManager and save your Properties in it and Access it.